# SearchWidget doesn't call onSearchRequested()

Tags: android, search

i got an activity with a searchwidget and a listview. If someone searches, all items not matching the query should get deleted of course. So i want do delete all items of the list and fill it with the smaller list. So i tried to pass my ArrayList to the new searchable Activity by adding it to the Bundle in the onSearchRequested Method. But this method isn't called when i performa search.

This is the code i got:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_player);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sv_sign_search_name);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    searchView.setFocusable(false);
    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra(SearchManager.APP_DATA);
        player = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("players");
        player = searchPlayers(query);
        showPlayers();
    } else {
        initializeScreen();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
     Bundle appData = new Bundle();
     appData.putParcelableArrayList("players", player);
     startSearch(null, false, appData, false);
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify meta-data in your Manifest for a searchable activity setup.  For example:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.SuperDuperActivity">
     <meta-data
          android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
          android:value=".activity.SearchResultsActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Then in your **SuperDuperActivity** onSearchRequested() will surely be called.